# Merging files while copying

Tags: batch-file, merge, copy

So, I'm trying to arrange a dos command or create a batch file, that will loop through all files and subfolders and each time a file is copied, it will be also merged with a standard text file.
For example:
We have file1.txt containing the string "A" and file2.txt containing the string "B", in C:\folder
We also have the file text.txt containing the string F, in C:\

I want to copy those two files, while each time merging them with text.txt, so I can get file1.txt containing the strings "AF" and file2.txt containing the strings "BF", in my new D:\ directory.

So far i can just copy the files. When I try to merge with text.txt, it merges all three of them together, creating file1.txt containing the strings "ABF".

The commands I have so far are:

```
FOR %%G IN ("C:\folder") DO copy %%G D:

FOR %%G IN ("C:\folder") DO copy %%G + text.txt D:
```

The first one is working. The second one messes everything up.

Comment: I assume you are on a Windows machine - Yes? If so, then this is ***not*** a DOS question.

Comment: So, apparently my mistake was I didn't have the command between ( ). Works like a charm now! It doesn't go through subfolders yet, but still 80% of the work is done automatically. Also, dbenham, valid point!

Comment: @Konstadinos, you could try a `FOR /R` command to loop through files (recurse subfolders). Syntax:
      `FOR /R [[drive:]path] %%parameter IN (set) DO command`

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure I'm on the same frequency, but I think this maybe what your trying to do:

```
FOR %%i IN ("C:\folder\*.txt") DO (copy %%i D:\)
FOR %%i IN ("D:\*.txt") DO (type C:\*.txt >> %%i)
```

Either way the `TYPE` command maybe useful to you for appending the output (redirect content) to an existing file.